# Python-Selenium: Select object by xpath works ~80% of the time, fails others

Tags: python, selenium

I have a program with several find_element/click statements and most work, but this is the only problem statement:

```
wait.until(lambda driver: browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td'))
print('Accessing Virtual Warehouse')
VirtWhse = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td')
VirtWhse.click()
```

the wait function was added because I thought maybe it was trying to click before the element was loaded. it doesn't seem to make any difference if it is added or not. it is defined as:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser,10)
```

I know that it is finding the element because my print statement is always outputted. also, I can see the link being underlined in the browser when I watch it being executed.

the problem is, it only seems to actually click on the link 80% of the time. The rest of the time, my wait.until function times out and the program crashes.
(EDIT- the wait function that times out is the next wait function, after the click, not the one in the code snippet.)

Can anyone explain why I'm having this reliability issue with this one element?

Comment: Can you check a situation when the program fails and check if the xPath of the element isn't changed on the site?.

Comment: @TomDanilov the xpath appears to be the same even when the program fails. part of the reason I added the wait function was to see if it found the element, then print "Accessing Virtual Warehouse" after the element was found. It seems like it finds the element 100% of the time (it prints the statement), but fails to click it some times.

Comment: Try use id or CSS, or add wait/retry.

Answer (score 0):

I added time.sleep(.5) before VirtWhse.click() per @JackWu and it seems to solve the issue.

I thought my initial wait.until function would prevent this from being needed, but I guess it just needs a little time between defining this particular object and selecting it for some reason.